# Entity Framework Code First migrations broken on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently having issues with Entity Framework in specific with regards to code first migrations. They were working fine on both my test database and on our server but obviously I have changed something that is causing them to not migrate to the most recent version on our Server. I've looked at the __migrations table in the database and it doesn't have my most recent change. From the stack trace below it looks like the framework is trying to recreate the database completely from scratch.

```
[InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'CustomerContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).]
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +286
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +483
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +177
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +274
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +77
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +21
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +83
   System.Linq.<DistinctIterator>d__63`1.MoveNext() +333
   BSGSupport.Controllers.CustomerController.Index() +385
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +186
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137
```

My current configuration file for the Context is

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        MigrationsDirectory = @"MigrationsCustomer";
        ContextKey = "BSGSupport.DAL.CustomerContext";
    }
```

Another thing I have noticed is in my Seed function the default values aren't getting applied to new databases. Not sure if this is part of this issue or something separate.

Comment: can you show the `context` class code ?

Comment: Try setting `Database.SetInitializer<CustomerContext>(null)` inside `Application_Start`, also check `_MigrationsHistory` table existence on your DB and remove it, and delete files under "Migration" directory on your project if exists. Then, run `update-database -verbose -force` on Package Manager as last resort (requires backup first).

Comment: Change your ConnectionString to the broken database. Type `Add-Migration "WhatHasChanged"` you should see a change in the migration.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I have tried setting the database initialize to null and all I get then is a message when trying to read the class with the added value that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Daniel changing the connection string and running the Update-Database command does seem to fix the issue. I still don't understand why I have to manually run the command as it was working fine without that before.

Comment: @BrendanRusso i said you should run `Add-Migration "WhatHasChanged"` first and then you should run `Update-Database`.
After you did that you will see what your error is. And afterwards you can start complaining why it occured.